# Why does my 24V DC brushless vibration motor overheat?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

Last year, I bought a 120W brushless vibration motor with 24V DC online for my food production machinery.

After using it for three months, I found the motor had overheating phenomenon.

I the searched much material online to find out the reasons of brushless DC motor overheating.

So far, I have collected these reasons:

- too high power supply voltage
- too low power supply voltage
- the burned core
- the winding surface is covered with dirt things
- broken fan
- wrong winding wirings
- brushless DC motor starts frequently
- high overload or mechanical resistance.

I eliminated these reasons for my motor, but this motor still overheats.

The motor technical specification can be found [here](https://peacosupport.com/motors/vibration-motor/dc-vibration-motor/120w-dc-brushless-vibration-motor). Does anyone know some other reason, or can anyone give me some guidance on selecting the right brushless vibration motor for my vibration motor projects?

Alternatively, I suppose I should buy another motor as a backup, then I would need to build a big fan to cool my food production place. Anyway, my food production cost will be increased.

Comment: Speak to the supplier is my advice. Who was the supplier?

Comment: Can you describe why you believe it is overheating?  It might get quite warm during normal operation.  Can you measure its temperature?

Comment: Outside surface of motor dirty, circulation of air around motor restricted, ambient temperature too high, operating speed too slow, repeat from first list operating load too high -- check twice.

Comment: If you cannot find any technical problem, is it possible that it simply needs better air flow, for example?